# How to remove automatic negative indent from Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs

When I write a paragraph in Google Documents, they get a very distinctive negative indent on the first line. I don't want that. I want my paragraphs to have no indent at all.

How do I get that?

Here is a screenshot showing the automatic negative indent:
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing that. What language are you localized to?

Comment: I'm using the `German` version. We have no such indentation here either, but it shows up.

Comment: Odd. I'm not seeing _any_ setting for indenting the first line of a paragraph. Is this a pure Google Docs document? Meaning, it's not a converted Word doc? Is this a regular Google account or a Google Apps account?

Comment: Wait. I found it. Let me take a couple of screen shots and post an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was tough to find.

First, make sure you have "Show ruler" checked under the **View** menu.

Then, in the ruler at the top of your document, I bet you see something like this:

[image: screen shot with hanging indent]

The little blue rectangle has the tooltip "First line indent" while the little blue triangle says "Left indent". In other words, the first line of your paragraph lines up with the rectangle, while the rest lines up with the triangle. To remove this you need to line them up, like so:

[image: screen shot - lined up indent]

Each paragraph appears to have its own setting, so you'll probably have to select all (or most) of your text and make the change to apply it more universally.

I'm guessing that you inadvertently moved this when first creating the document.

More information on the [Page setup](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183618) support page.

Answer (score 3):

To remove this automatic indent in all documents, you have to reset the "styles" to default.

First click on the **Normal Text** button, then **Options**, then **reset styles** and finally **Save as my default styles**.

Answer (score 1):

Format > Align & Indent -> Indentation Options -> Special Indent: Hanging Indent -> None.

Answer (score 0):

In your Google doc:

1. Select all
2. Right click and choose "clear formatting"

You may have to reapply some fonts, but this got rid of the extremely annoying indentation problem for me :)